# TypeScript type checking JSX children

Tags: typescript, reactjs

My TypeScript Version is `2.3.2`

According to this [Type checking JSX children](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/15160)

The following code should work:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

interface TestProps {
    children: string | JSX.Element;
}

const Foo = (props: TestProps) => <div>{props.children}</div>;

// Error on Foo
ReactDOM.render(
    <Foo>
        <div>Test</div>
    </Foo>,
    document.getElementById('content'),
);
```

But i get the following compilation error:

```
TestTsxChildren> tsc --version
Version 2.3.2
TestTsxChildren> tsc
main.tsx(11,5): error TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TestProps'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'TestProps'.
    Property 'children' is missing in type '{}'.
```

What did i do wrong? Or did i not understand what the issue was trying to fix?

Comment: Yes you are right, but that has nothing to do with the error i get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the definition file for React is not updated.

The definition file needs to include `interface ElementChildrenAttribute { children: {}; }` so that TypeScript compiler known the name of the "children" property.

PR to update the definition file: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/16327)